# npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: @angular/cli@latest

Tags: angular

I am running the npm install -g @angular/cli command from the command window in admin mode and I am getting the following error message:

npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: @angular/cli@latest

A co worker of mine has no issues with this command and I have run the command in months past.  I also have disconnected my land line and went wireless on multiple networks (some with security and some without) but I still get this error?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: maybe take a look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180668/angular-ng-update-angular-returns-401-unauthorized/53696690#53696690

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, tried reinstalling node&npm via nvm-windows to no avail. Eventually I found out that I had apparently logged into npm a long time ago and that account was blocked/expired/I don't care. After running "npm logout" I was able to install the package again. Interestingly, it was only returning 401 for some packages, @angular/cli included.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, but on a different package, when using npm with a .npmrc file going through an Azure DevOps registry.  The problem was that my credentials expired and had to run the command again to get a new token:

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```