# Angular `ng update @angular/...` returns `401 Unauthorized`

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

`npm -v` returns `6.0.0`

`node -v` returns `v10.0.0`

Angular CLI local and global version is `6.0.0`

I create a new package with `ng new sample`, run `npm install` without issue, and then I try `ng update @angular/core` or `ng update @angular/cli` and get `401 Unauthorized` in response.

Trying to run update on an already Angular 6 repository does seem redundant but I also have this issue with an Angular 5 repository.

[image: ng5-sample git:(ng6) ✗ ng update @angular/core, 401 Unauthorized]

I don't have a lot to go on from this error, is it something to do specifically with `ng update` or more likely to be some unrelated configuration outside of it?

Comment: Did you update @angular/cli before with success? (For the angular 5 app)

Comment: I seem to remember running `ng update @angular/cli` at least once in the Angular 5 app without issue to actually make the jump to CLI version 6.0.0, but the moment I moved onto `@angular/core` it became like this.

Comment: Global and local versions are both 6.0.0 now.

Comment: having the same issue while trying to follow https://update.angular.io/ to update from angular 5.2 to 6.0.0... Running under windows node 9.8.0 and npm 5.6.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was struggling with the same error message. For me it was caused by a custom `.npmrc` in the project directory which contained information about howto connect to our npm registry.

Here's how I resolved it:

1. removed the file during the update (`mv .npmrc backup.npmrc`)
2. removed all dependencies to artifacts from our internal npm registry from the `package.json`
3. ran `ng update @angular/cli`
4. moved file back to old position `mv backup.npmrc .npmrc`
5. ran `npm install` (just to make sure)

I also created an angular-cli issue at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10704

Comment: Works for me and saves me a lot of time doing it by hand! Thx

Comment: Working. I first needed to set the registry to the default npm registry instead of my private one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the accepted answer this problem comes from having a custom registry defined somewhere in your configuration. Via .rc files such as `.yarnrc` or `.npmrc` or set directly with the `npm config set registry <url>` or `yarn config set <name>:registry <url>`. You don't need to undo these registry configurations to work around the issue! The `ng update` command will take a registry url as an argument. However, you will have to remove any reference to packages that rely on your custom registry. Don't worry the command will tell you what the offending packages are, just run the command like so:

**for yarn:**

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com`

**for npm:**

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --registry https://registry.npmjs.org`

Should result in an error like:
`Not found : @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro`

Then you can temporarily remove the offending package from your dependencies in package.json and try again.

Answer (score 0):

By chance, were you running the app when you tried to update? 
I had the same issue and was able to update from 5.29 to 6.0.0 after stopping the app process and installing the latest cli globally.

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to be this. A minor difference in behaviour this morning in that it just hanged instead of `401 Unauthorized`, but unsure if related.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Here is how i resolved it.

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
ng update
ng update --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying anything else, go to *Artifactory UI Home* and in *Set Me Up* widget scroll to npm repo you provide for *registry* in *.npmrc*. Click it and then type in your password in the popup to generate config and copy&paste the part with *auth*, *username*, *email* and *registry*. Auth is different than you would expect (it's not the API key in user profile, neither the encrypted password as some sources suggest). This have caused me many problems until I found the way to generate config in *Artifactory UI*.
Btw:

- I didn't have to set any scoped repos to run *ng update* command
- npm auth config works since Angular 7 - this particular commit in angular/devkit https://github.com/angular/devkit/pull/982/commits/123f13cf99413f8424d30ee777600be4f30f5695